# Adding custom classes to the anchor tag within the WordPress Nav

Tags: php, css, wordpress, class, menu

I'm trying to add custom classses to the `<a>` elements instead of the `<li>`elements in the navigation menu. The users can change the custom classes from the backend (Using appearances > menu > css classes optional).

I have created & added the following to my functions.php to add a class to it...and it half works. Its just not outputting the custom menu css classes.

```
function add_nav_class($output) {

$class_names = wp_nav_menu(array ('menu_class'      => '',)
);

$output= preg_replace('/<a/', '<a class="'.$class_names.'"', $output, -1);
return $output;

}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'add_nav_class');
```

how to call the 'css classes optional' bit from WordPress?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at following guide: http://sevenspark.com/how-to/how-to-add-a-custom-class-to-a-wordpress-menu-item

Comment: i already know how to do that Robin, im trying to add the class to the Anchor tag only & not the li

Comment: I've updated my answer, should be fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find an easier way to do it. And it's getting a little complicated if you're relatively new to wordpress.

**1.)** At first you'll have to create a custom Walker_Nav_Menu. You can do that by extending from it. 
**Edit:** Make an extra php file e.g. my-walker-nav.php and include it to your functions.php, that'll be more clean than all code in `functions.php`

```
class My_Custom_Walker_Nav extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    // Code
}
```

What you wanna do now is to copy the base code (line 17 to 190) out of the [standard Walker_Nav_Menu](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.1/src//wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L0).

**2.)** The second step is to add additional code to the function `start_el` to use the current menu item's ID to fetch it's meta information for the key `_menu_item_classes`.

```
/* Get the optional css class(es)*/
$optional_css_classes = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_classes', true );
```

**3.)** Next we compare the current items menu css classes with our fetched one's from meta data. See Php array function [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php). If both arrays contain the same value it'll be removed. In our case that would be the optional css class.

```
/* Remove all optional css from current li element's class*/
$item->classes = array_diff($item->classes, $optional_css_classes);
```

Now we've removed the optional class from the `<li>` element.

**4.)** Step number four requires us to add the optional css classes to the `<a>` element.

Find following code around line 117 at `nav-menu-template.php`:

```
$atts = array();
$atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->title )   ? $item->title  : '';
$atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )  ? $item->target : '';
$atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )     ? $item->xfn    : '';
```

And add the next line of code to it:

```
$atts['class']  = ! empty( $optional_css_classes) ? implode(' ', $optional_css_classes): '';
```

**5.)** Don't forget to use your built `My_Custom_Walker_Nav`. At the template part where you call `wp_nav_menu`to declare your navigation menu (usually in `header.php`), you should add the attribute `walker`to the array.

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
    /*......*/
    'walker' => new My_Custom_Walker_Nav())
);
```

Now you should be could to go.

Find the complete custom Walker_Nav_Menu [here](https://gist.github.com/robsn/5e33eae3a2137fa0a213)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Thats really helpful. Ive just taken a look at the code above you created & its quite similar by the fact it adds the class to the anchor tag. but it still doesnt output the exact data which is in the 'CSS CLASSES' field from the backend. Im quite new to WP so im unsure what is wrong. Can you elaborate on the 'class-css' so it will work on my site? At present its outputting the following (html) <a href="http://www.websiteco.uk/products/" class="class-css">Products</a>

Comment: I want it to output the data entered from the Custom CSS Field in the wordpress backend. So something like <a href="websiteco.uk/products/"; class="redbackground-class">Products</a> At present its outputting exactly <a href="websiteco.uk/products/"; class="class-css">Products</a> fore every menu item (its not dynamic)

Comment: If that works for you, i'd be nice to mark it as correct. Thank you